# Duplicating canvas in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm a beginner with JavaScript and i'm trying to duplicate the canvas in pdf.js so i will have two canvases with the same PDF. What i'll try to do later is to synchronize both PDFs.
i'm using this example ([prevnext.html](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/learning/prevnext.html)) :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Previous/Next example</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>'Previous/Next' example</h1>

<div>
  <button id="prev">Previous</button>
  <button id="next">Next</button>
  &nbsp; &nbsp;
  <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
</div>

<div>
  <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>

</div>

<!-- for legacy browsers add compatibility.js -->
<!--<script src="../compatibility.js"></script>-->

<script src="../pdfdemo/build/pdf.js"></script>

<script id="script">
  //
  // If absolute URL from the remote server is provided, configure the CORS
  // header on that server.
  //
  var url = 'http://www.hbrtest3.com/files/sheena/pdfdemo/Getting_Started.pdf';



  //
  // Disable workers to avoid yet another cross-origin issue (workers need
  // the URL of the script to be loaded, and dynamically loading a cross-origin
  // script does not work).
  //
  // PDFJS.disableWorker = true;

  //
  // In cases when the pdf.worker.js is located at the different folder than the
  // pdf.js's one, or the pdf.js is executed via eval(), the workerSrc property
  // shall be specified.
  //
  // PDFJS.workerSrc = '../../build/pdf.worker.js';

  var pdfDoc = null,
      pageNum = 1,
      pageRendering = false,
      pageNumPending = null,
      scale = 0.8,
      canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


  /**
   * Get page info from document, resize canvas accordingly, and render page.
   * @param num Page number.
   */
  function renderPage(num) {
    pageRendering = true;
    // Using promise to fetch the page
    pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(function(page) {
      var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
      canvas.height = viewport.height;
      canvas.width = viewport.width;

      // Render PDF page into canvas context
      var renderContext = {
        canvasContext: ctx,
        viewport: viewport
      };
      var renderTask = page.render(renderContext);;

      // Wait for rendering to finish
      renderTask.promise.then(function () {
        pageRendering = false;
        if (pageNumPending !== null) {
          // New page rendering is pending
          renderPage(pageNumPending);
          pageNumPending = null;
        }
      });



    // Update page counters
    document.getElementById('page_num').textContent = pageNum;
  }

  /**
   * If another page rendering in progress, waits until the rendering is
   * finised. Otherwise, executes rendering immediately.
   */
  function queueRenderPage(num) {
    if (pageRendering) {
      pageNumPending = num;
    } else {
      renderPage(num);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Displays previous page.
   */
  function onPrevPage() {
    if (pageNum <= 1) {
      return;
    }
    pageNum--;
    queueRenderPage(pageNum);
  }
  document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener('click', onPrevPage);

  /**
   * Displays next page.
   */
  function onNextPage() {
    if (pageNum >= pdfDoc.numPages) {
      return;
    }
    pageNum++;
    queueRenderPage(pageNum);
  }
  document.getElementById('next').addEventListener('click', onNextPage);

  /**
   * Asynchronously downloads PDF.
   */
  PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(function (pdfDoc_) {
    pdfDoc = pdfDoc_;
    document.getElementById('page_count').textContent = pdfDoc.numPages;

    // Initial/first page rendering
    renderPage(pageNum);
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: are you getting any error? I see only one Canvas in your code. Where is the other one?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.clone()` from jquery to duplicate the canvas in pdf.js